# Running a Script and Using MySQL Workbench: Error

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, mysql-workbench

I'm using Windows 8.1, 64 bit, MySQL 5.6.23.

I'm using a document(movie_db.sql) from a learning exercise.  I downloaded & saved the script(C:\Users\Reed\OneDrive\SQLProjects\TeamTreeHouseDatabaseFoundations\movie_db.sql).

Opened the script in MySQL: File> Open sql script> selcted the above script > "lightning bolt" > result in Action Output shows a warning in row 1:

```js
1 1 19:39:01 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `treehouse_movie_db` 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s):
 1008 Can't drop database 'treehouse_movie_db'; database doesn't exist 0.000 sec
```

Created a query > SELECT * FROM movies; > "lightning bolt" > got the following:

```js
5 42 19:44:07 SELECT * FROM movies
 LIMIT 0, 1000 Fetching... 0.000 sec / ?
   
0 43 19:44:07 SELECT * FROM movies
 LIMIT 0, 1000 Error: Error formatting SQL query: empty string given as argument for ! character
```

Screen Shots:

MySQL Home:
http://screencast.com/t/tIDDDTDydvbE

document/SQL Script:
http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/DBFoundations/stage_2/movie_db.sql

Startup/Shutdown Server is running:
http://screencast.com/t/yoH1UOzCw

Action Output warning 1:
http://screencast.com/t/hr88FTb9t

Query 1:
http://screencast.com/t/xBkvXrDKE

Question:

I'm new to MySQL, looking to understand what's going on here & how it can be corrected.  Thank you.

Comment: Double-click on the database name so that it becomes bold. Credits: https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/error-executing-query

Comment: lol. yeah that worked.  Seems a little silly to me, but it's not my job to design the software, only to use it.  Thanks.

Comment: It would have been nice if the example had instruction like `use <database-name>`. That would have made life easier for everyone using that database.

Comment: Sounds like you know alllll about database foundations.  Give me an email if you would like to talk databases or java sometime.  reedwilliams8404@gmail.com